# How to deserialize this xml using XStream?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream, xml-deserialization

I am trying to de serialize following xml into Java object using XStream.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<corpus>
<s id="1">
  <tree style="penn">
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Brooklyn) (NN man))
    (VP (VBD accused)
      (PP (IN of)
        (NP (NN forgery))))
    (. .)))
  </tree>
<dependencies style="typed">
  <dep type="nn">
    <governor idx="2">man</governor>
    <dependent idx="1">Brooklyn</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nsubj">
    <governor idx="3">accused</governor>
    <dependent idx="2">man</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="prep_of">
    <governor idx="3">accused</governor>
    <dependent idx="5">forgery</dependent>
  </dep>
</dependencies>
</s>

<s id="2">
  <tree style="penn">
(ROOT
  (S
    (S
      (NP (DT A)
        (ADJP (CD 36) (NN year) (JJ old))
        (NNP Brooklyn) (NN man))
      (VP (VBZ is)
        (VP (VBG facing)
          (NP (JJ several) (NN felony) (NNS charges))
          (SBAR (IN after)
            (S
              (NP (PRP he))
              (VP (VBD was)
                (VP (VBN accused)
                  (PP (IN of)
                    (S
                      (VP (VBG giving)
                        (NP
                          (NP (DT a) (JJ forged) (NN prescription))
                          (PP (IN for)
                            (NP (NN oxycodone))))
                        (PP (TO to)
                          (NP (DT a) (JJ local) (NN pharmacist)))))))))))))
    (, ,)
    (NP (NNP Endicott) (NNS police))
    (VP (VBD said))
    (. .)))
  </tree>
<dependencies style="typed">
  <dep type="det">
    <governor idx="6">man</governor>
    <dependent idx="1">A</dependent>
  </dep>
</s>
</corpus>
```

I have created following classes for this xml structure :

```
public class Corpus {

    private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<Sentence>();

    public List<Sentence> getSentences() {
        return sentences;
    }

    public void setSentences(List<Sentence> sentences) {
        this.sentences = sentences;
    }

    public void add(Sentence sentence) {
        this.sentences.add(sentence);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Sentence {

    private int id;
    private Tree tree;
    private Dependencies dependencies;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Tree getTree() {
        return tree;
    }
    public void setTree(Tree tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
    }

    public Dependencies getDependencies() {
        return dependencies;
    }

    public void setDependencies(Dependencies dependencies) {
        this.dependencies = dependencies;
    }

    public Sentence(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I have other classes also for each element but I have not mentioned those classes here. When I run the project, I get following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: s : s : s : s
---- Debugging information ----
message             : s : s
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : s : s
class               : com.srl.SSAOutputModel.Corpus
required-type       : com.srl.SSAOutputModel.Corpus
path                : /corpus/s
line number         : 1
```

Following code tries to deserialize the xml

```
    xstream.alias("corpus", Corpus.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(Corpus.class, "sentences");

    xstream.useAttributeFor(Sentence.class, "id");
    xstream.aliasField("id", Sentence.class, "id");

    xstream.alias("S", Sentence.class);

    xstream.useAttributeFor(Tree.class, "style");
    xstream.aliasField("style",Tree.class, "style");

    xstream.omitField(Tree.class, "content");
    xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);

    Corpus cx = (Corpus) xstream.fromXML(lines);
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Smells like classpath or classloader hell... please double- and triple-check if your `Corpus` class is on the classpath when you run the application

Comment: @Andreas_D, I have included Xstream and xpp jar files in my class path. Is there anything else I need to add into classpath?

Comment: @Shekhar - the error message leads to the idea, that `com.srl.SSAOutputModel.Corpus` is not found - either not on the classpath or loaded by a different classloader... is it a standalone application or part of some server/client architecture?

Comment: @Andreas_D, its a standalone application.

Comment: @Shekhar - a 10% chance but worth a try: decapitalize the alias for sentence: `xstream.alias("s", Sentence.class);`

Comment: @Andreas_D, thanks a lot. I decapitalized the alisa for sentence and its working now. Thanks a million. How can I make such a mistake?

Comment: @Shekhar - *wow* - I make an answer for this... stupid me too, saw it right away, but was 100% sure that xml tags are case-insensitve which is plain wrong ;) NeedMoreCoffeeError ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer summarizes the solution we already posted in the comment section.

This is the offending line that cause the error:

```
xstream.alias("S", Sentence.class);
```

[xml-tags are case sensitive](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_syntax.asp) and the tag name in the source document is `<s>` while the alias is defined for `<S>`.

Changing this line to

```
xstream.alias("s", Sentence.class);
```

obviously solved the problem :)